# Applying Multiple WHERE conditions on a single Column of a Table

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL Database and here is the Sample Data. It is a large dataset and I am using the first two rows for example.

```
Price | Moduletype
172   | 1
173   | 2
```

What I want is to query the data based on the Moduletype numbers 1 and 2. Moduletype1 will have the prices belonging to it and Moduletype2 will have prices belonging to it.

For Example:

```
Moduletype1 | ModuleType2
172         | 173
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to post exactly what you'd want as a result?  It sounds like you want a single row in the result with two columns, one with a value of 172 and one with a value of 173.  Is that correct?  Assuming that your actual table has more than two rows, how do you know which rows you want to combine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123321/discussion-between-uttasarga-singh-and-justin-cave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Query which helps to select the Price based on the Module Type.

```
Select
(case when i.moduletype = 1 then i.PRICE else -1 end)RTL_PRC_AMT,
(case when i.moduletype = 2 then i.PRICE else -1 end)ADMN_FEE_AMT
from TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes you never have more than one price per moduletype:

```
select max(price) filter (where moduletype = 1) as module_type_1,
       max(price) filter (where moduletype = 2) as module_type_2
from the_table;
```

If you want to see multiple rows per moduletype, maybe you want this:

```
select t1.price as module_type_1,
       t2.price as module_type_2
from (
  select price, row_number() over (order by price) as rn
  from the_table 
  where moduletype = 1
) t1
  full join (
    select price, row_number() over (order by price) as rn
    from the_table 
    where moduletype = 2
  ) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Or alternatively (same idea, different approach):

```
select x.*
from (
  select array_agg(price) filter (where moduletype = 1) as moduletype1,
         array_agg(price) filter (where moduletype = 2) as moduletype2
  from the_table
) t
  cross join unnest (t.moduletype1, t.moduletype2) as x (module_type_1, module_type_2)
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your comment. So I have a large table out of which I posted the first two rows as an example. What I want is to create a view for the two columns named as module1 and module2, which will have all the prices which belongs to module 1 and module2 respectively.